# Can't open database with pyodbc

Tags: python, database, driver, pyodbc

I'm sure this is a stupidly simple issue but I just can't sort it out.  I'm trying to open a local database with pyodbc but it won't let me.
The database and script are on the same path, there are no passwords.  I only have one installation of Python on my system - Anaconda 3, and this is where pyodbc installed itself when I used PIP to install the Python 3.5, 64 bit whl file from Christoph Gohlke

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=tblGrid.mdb;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Thanks

Comment: Is tblGrid.mdb an Access database?

Comment: Yes. 2002-2003 format

Comment: Why not open it with the Access ODBC driver then? I'm not aware that the SQL Server ODBC driver can be used to connect to an Access database.

Comment: Would I just change my syntax so that the driver was Driver={Access ODBC}?

Comment: No the connection string syntax is different for different databases. Your best bet is to go into Control Panel and set up an ODBC DSN for your Access database. Then you can connect to it with `pyodbc.connect('DSN=mydsn')`.

Comment: However, there is an example of connecting direclty to an Access database here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access.

Comment: The script that I'm writing is supposed to be able to open and read any *.mdb file on my system given just a path and filename though, wouldn't the method that you suggest require me setting up a DSN for all of my files?  (Sorry, I appreciate I didn't mention this before)

Comment: It's OK I have added an answer showing how to open the file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Microsoft Access ODBC driver to open an `*.mdb` file.

Here is an example of connecting:

```
pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\some\path\tblGrid.mdb')
```

Comment: I've just given this a go but get the following error: pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Have you got the Access ODBC driver installed? You can check for it in Control Panel. If not, you can download it from Microsoft (it's free).

Comment: Also, you might need the full path to the database file.

Comment: Doesn't look like I have the driver.  It appears in my User DSN list, but when I select it and click "configure" the error message "The setup routines for the Microsoft Access Drive (*.dmb) ODBC driver could not be found.  Please reinstall the driver".  I'll see if I can find it online

Comment: Think my problem originates from a clash of 32 and 64 bit software.  I have Office 2007 which only comes in 32 bit but am running Python 64 bit.